# Append environment definition

Tags: math-mode, spacing, environments

Is there a way to append an environment definition, something like `\appendenvironment` akin to `\(re)newenvironment`?

Specifically, I'd like to reduce the horizontal spacing after the `pmatrix` environment to have punctuation symbols nice and snug with the closing parenthesis. The default spacing is

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    D_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & -i & i & -1\\
        1 & -i & i & -1\\
        1 & -i & i & -1\\
        1 & -i & i & -1
    \end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Adding `\mkern-6mu` or `\!\!` after `\end{pmatrix}` results in the much nicer appearance.

[image]

Is there some way to have this negative space inserted after every `pmatrix` without using `\renewenvironment` and copying the whole environment definition to my preamble?

Comment: Quick and dirty: `\usepackage{xpatch}\xapptocmd{\endpmatrix}{\mkern-6mu}{}{}`.

Comment: The `etoolbox` package has `\AtEndEnvironment{}` command

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `\AfterEndEnvironment`  would be better. The argument of `\AtEndEnvironment` is appended _before_ `\endXXX`, and in this case it would add the negative space to the last entry of the matrix, not after the parenthesis `:-)`

Comment: @campa: True, I forgot that it should be done after the environment

Comment: @campa: Willing to add an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whereas [campa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/82917/campa)  suggested a `\xpatchcmd` way I use `\AfterEndEnvironment` from `etoolbox` package and as another alternative method the `\g@addto@macro` which does not need an extra package because it is a LaTeX kernel macro.

I prefer the `\AfterEndEnvironment` method since it is a little bit cleaner.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{etoolbox}


\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    D_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & -i & i & -1\\
        1 & -i & i & -1\\
        1 & -i & i & -1\\
        1 & -i & i & -1
    \end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}


\AfterEndEnvironment{pmatrix}{\mkern-6mu}

\begin{equation}
    D_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & -i & i & -1\\
        1 & -i & i & -1\\
        1 & -i & i & -1\\
        1 & -i & i & -1
    \end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}

Now with bmatrix and then with \verb!\g@addto@macro\endbmatrix!

\begin{equation}
    D_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -i & i & -1\\
        1 & -i & i & -1\\
        1 & -i & i & -1\\
        1 & -i & i & -1
    \end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}


\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\endbmatrix}{\mkern-6mu}%
\makeatother

\begin{equation}
    D_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -i & i & -1\\
        1 & -i & i & -1\\
        1 & -i & i & -1\\
        1 & -i & i & -1
    \end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]